# Node.js Twitter bot keeps giving 'Unauthorized' error with Twitter API, how to troubleshoot?

Tags: javascript, node.js, twitter, twitter-oauth

I am trying to create a twitter bot with the basic subscription of the twitter API, Basically the bot looks for recent tweets it is mentioned in and replies to that. I wrote some code with nodejs but it keeps giving me an unauthorized message from the api, how can I get it to work?

```
const needle = require('needle');
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const OAuth = require('oauth-1.0a');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const qs = require('querystring');

const consumer_key = process.env.CONSUMER_KEY;
const consumer_secret = process.env.CONSUMER_SECRET;
const bearer_token = process.env.BEARER_TOKEN;

const endpointUrlSearch = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/recent";
const endpointUrlTweet = `https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets`;

let counter = 0;
let repliedTweets = new Set();

const oauth = OAuth({
    consumer: {
        key: consumer_key,
        secret: consumer_secret
    },
    signature_method: 'HMAC-SHA1',
    hash_function(base_string, key) {
        return crypto
            .createHmac('sha1', key)
            .update(base_string)
            .digest('base64');
    },
});

async function getRequest() {
    const params = {
        'query': '@Botname',
        'tweet.fields': 'author_id'
    }

    const res = await needle('get', endpointUrlSearch, params, {
        headers: {
            "User-Agent": "v2RecentSearchJS",
            "authorization": `Bearer ${bearer_token}`
        }
    })

    if (res.body) {
        return res.body;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Unsuccessful request');
    }
}

async function postRequest(consumer_key, consumer_secret, tweet_id, screen_name) {
    const token = {
        key: consumer_key,
        secret: consumer_secret
    };

    let replyText = 'reply';
    counter++;
    if (counter === 10) {
        replyText = 'reply reply';
        counter = 0;
    }

    const data = {
        "text": '@' + screen_name + ' ' + replyText,
        "reply": { "in_reply_to_tweet_id": tweet_id }
    };

    const authHeader = oauth.toHeader(oauth.authorize({
        url: endpointUrlTweet,
        method: 'POST'
    }, token));

    const req = await fetch(endpointUrlTweet, {
        method: 'POST',
        body: JSON.stringify(data),
        headers: {
            Authorization: authHeader["Authorization"],
            'user-agent': "v2CreateTweetJS",
            'content-type': "application/json",
            'accept': "application/json"
        }
    });

    if (req.body) {
        return req.body;
    } else {
        throw new Error('Unsuccessful request');
    }
}

(async () => {
    try {
        const response = await getRequest();
        console.log(response);
        let tweets = [];

        if (response && response.data && response.data.length > 0) {
            tweets = response.data;
        } else if (response && response.includes && response.includes.tweets && response.includes.tweets.length > 0) {
            tweets = response.includes.tweets;
        } else {
            console.log('No tweets found in the response.');
            return;
        }

        for (let tweet of tweets) {
            // Check if the tweet has been replied to
            if (repliedTweets.has(tweet.id)) {
                continue;
            }

            const replyResponse = await postRequest(consumer_key, consumer_secret, tweet.id, tweet.author_id);
            console.log(replyResponse);
            repliedTweets.add(tweet.id);
        }







    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        process.exit(-1);
    }
})();
```

Logged message:

`{   "title": "Unauthorized",   "type": "about:blank",   "status": 401,   "detail": "Unauthorized" } No tweets found in the response.`

I tried to play with different types of OAuth but it is not really helping, I also have my API Settings on read & write so that cant be it.